# Null Pointer Exception Error .Please help me

Tags: java, exception, null, public, lang

I have 2 classes : Persoana(person) and PersoanaList(to store all the Persoana objects)

Persoana.java:

```
public class Persoana {
    private String nume;
    private String prenume;
    private ContCurent contCurent;
    private ContDepozit contDepozit;

    public Persoana(String n,String pr,ContCurent cC){//are doar cont curent
        nume=n;
        prenume =pr;
        contCurent=cC;
    }
    public Persoana(String n,String pr,ContDepozit cD){//are doar cont depozit
        nume=n;
        prenume =pr;
        contDepozit=cD;
    }
    public Persoana(String n,String pr,ContCurent cC,ContDepozit cD){//are atat cont curent cat si depozit
        nume=n;
        prenume =pr;
        contCurent =cC;
        contDepozit=cD;
    }
    public String getNume(){
        return nume;
    }
    public String getPrenume(){
        return prenume;
    }
    public void afisare(){
        System.out.println(nume);
        System.out.println(prenume);
        System.out.println(contDepozit.numarCard);
        System.out.println(contDepozit.pin);
        System.out.println(contDepozit.sold);
        contDepozit.getDataScadenta();

    }
    public int getPin(){
        return contCurent.pin;

    }
```

The PersoanaList file :

public class PersoanaList {

```
 Persoana[] perslist = new Persoana[20];
int i=1;
public void adauga(Persoana a)
{

    perslist[i]=a;
    i++;


}
public void afisare(){
    for(int j=1;j<=perslist.length;j++)
    {
        perslist[j].afisare();
    }
}
public boolean cautare(String a,int b){
    boolean check=true;
    for(int j=1;j<=perslist.length;j++)
    {

        if(perslist[j].getNume().equals(a) && perslist[j].getPin()==b)
        check= true;
        else
            check= false;

    }
    return check;




}
public int marime(){
    return perslist.length;
}
```

}

Each Persoana have a name and pin .
The method "cautare " will search in array and if exists pin and name.If exists return true(kinda like login);

I have this error :java.lang.NullPointerException
Can anyone help me? Please ..

Ps : perslist[j].getNume() - isn't null , neither ..getPin()

Comment: On what line do you get the exception?

Comment: please post the whole error message you got

Comment: Stack trace would have been good as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the NullPointerException (NPE) in one of your loops in the `PersoanaList` class.  For example:

```
public boolean cautare(String a,int b){
    boolean check=true;
    for(int j=1;j<=perslist.length;j++)
{

    if(perslist[j].getNume().equals(a) && perslist[j].getPin()==b)
```

Since unless you've completely filled your `perslist` variable, you'll hit an array item that is null, giving you a NPE when `.getName()` is called.

After you fix that though, you'll probably hit an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException since you are using 1 to n for your array indices.  Arrays start at 0 and go to n-1.  So for 20 array items, you would reference them as 0 to 19.

Comment: The PersonList is populated from main .

    ContDepozit cD = new ContDepozit("Ro34190442y74y43", 1234, 400, d1);
    ContCurent cC = new ContCurent("Ro34190442y74y43",1234,400,350);
    Persoana pers1 = new Persoana("Maxim","Alexandru", cC,cD);
    PersoanaList pl = new PersoanaList();
    pl.adauga(pers1);
    pl.adauga(pers1);
    if( pl.cautare("Maxim", 1234)==true)
        System.out.println("find");
       else
        System.out.println("error");

Comment: for(int j=0;j<perslist.length;j++)
      {
    System.out.println(perslist[j].getNume());
    if(perslist[j].getNume().equals(a) && perslist[j].getPin()==b)
<br>
I add this 
 ***System.out.println(perslist[j].getNume());*** to see if perslist.getnume is null.
And something weird happen.
The 4 name are printed in console but after printing I still receive this error:
*

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
     at PersoanaList.cautare(PersoanaList.java:24)
     at Main.main(Main.java:24)*